# Why returning a std::vector is still making a copy?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a class that is going to create a pretty big array of data that I don't want to be copied around. For all considerations, it is immutable (read only) for anybody outside my class.

Here's a concept code that shows how I want to implement it:

```
class C {
public:
    C();
    std::vector<int> const& get_vector() { return m_vector; }
private:
    std::vector<int> m_vector;
};

C::C()
{
    m_vector.push_back(1);
    m_vector.push_back(2);
}

void DisplayVector(std::vector<int> const& new_v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<new_v.size(); i++)
        std::cout << new_v[i] << std::endl;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C myobj;
    std::vector<int> v = myobj.get_vector();
    v.push_back(3);

    DisplayVector(v);
}
```

When I step through this code, I see a given memory address for m_vector and the first element of its array (using the begin iterator).

When I return from get_vector, the vector "v" and its first element have a completely different memory address. 
v.push_back(3) doesn't have any problem modifying v (since it looks it's a copy)

When I call DisplayVector, then it works as I expected and new_v addresses are the same as main v.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: To prevent it from making a copy, use `std::vector<int> &v = myobj.get_vector();`

Comment: @Smac89: you surely meant `std::vector<int> const &v = myobj.get_vector();`?

Comment: @DietmarKühl right ofc

Comment: @Smac89: on the other hand, then `v.push_back(3)` won't work. It seems, the question in unclear in what it tried to be achieved...

Comment: Exactly. Now that you have a reference, it turns out that you can't add stuff to it outside the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You explicitly created a copy with

```
std::vector<int> v = myobj.get_vector();
```

which you can modify since `v`is a plain `vector<int>`. Here `v` got copy-constructed.

To instead bind a reference (which has to be `const` because of `get_vector`'s return type) use

```
const std::vector<int>& v = myobj.get_vector();
```

or just

```
const auto& v = myobj.get_vector();
```

Comment: I see. What I'm trying to do as the designer of class C is to remove that decision from the client. I guess to do that I'll have to return a pointer to vector?

Comment: If you want no copying of the return value return a type which cannot be copy constructed.

Comment: You mean something that is not a vector?

Comment: @PaduMerloti the client should have the decision. It's good style to not force anything on the client.

Comment: @PaduMerloti maybe you should be returning begin and end iterators instead. The client can still copy the data, but it makes the intent clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    C myobj;
    std::vector<int> v = myobj.get_vector();
```

After executing this code, you have *two* vectors; the instance variable `myobj.m_vector` and `v`.